# Fluent-bit parsing json in side of a string

Tags: regex, kubernetes, fluentd, fluent-bit

I have a k8s logging stack set up like this:
fluent-bit => fluentd => elastic

I have a working set up with this config:

fluent-bit.conf

```
[SERVICE]
Daemon Off
Parsers_File custom_parsers.conf
HTTP_Server On
HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
Health_Check On

[INPUT]
Name             tail
Path             /var/log/containers/*.log
DB               /var/log/flb_kube.db
Tag              kube.*
Refresh_Interval 5
Mem_Buf_Limit    128MB
Buffer_Chunk_Size 64KB
Buffer_Max_Size 128KB
Skip_Long_Lines  Off
Parser           crio


[FILTER]
Name kubernetes
Match kube.*
Merge_Log On
Keep_Log On
K8S-Logging.Parser On
K8S-Logging.Exclude On
Buffer_Size 256KB
Annotations Off
Labels On


[OUTPUT]
Match kube.*
Name forward
Host fluentd-collector.fluent.svc
Port 24224
tls off
tls.verify off

[OUTPUT]
Match kube.*
Name stdout

#custom_parsers.conf
[PARSER]
Name  crio
Format regex
reserve_data true
Regex ^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<logtag>[^ ]*) (?<log>.*)$
Time_Key    time
Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z
Time_Keep    On
```

logs are showing on elastic correctly, and when we have a JSON log coming in crio  parsing its just fine.

What im stuck with is, some of our logs have a json inside of a string inside the log key:

`[info]  [testing 1 of 2] some string here smplog::{"application":"test","abc":"high","version":"0.2.1"}`

I'm looking for catching the JSON after `smplog::` and parse that.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using data-prepper in combination with a grok parser?

Comment: there is the nest filter for that
https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/nest